# how do you link bootstrap with angularJS when it comes to pagnation?

Tags: angularjs

I have data in my database which i use calling httprequestcall for example:

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in cList.Page.Output.CustomerList.Customer">
<td><a href="#/CustomerSearch/{{c._CustomerKey}}" >{{c._CustomerID}}</a></td>
</tr></table><br/><br/>
<div class="pagination">
  <ul>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Prev</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="search(1)">1</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="search(2)">2</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="search(3)">3</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="search(4)">4</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="search(5)">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want a solution in which when i click next it should dynamically check the page number which is provided in the API itself to diplay the next set of page numbers as like 1,2,3,4 it should come 4,5,6,7

Answer (score 2):

You can use the data in your template (just as you are using it to display your customers):

```
<ul>
  <li ng-class="{disabled : cList.Page.Number == 1}"><a href="#">Prev</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="search(1)">{{1*cList.Page.Number}}</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="search(2)">{{2*cList.Page.Number}}</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="search(3)">{{3*cList.Page.Number}}</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="search(4)">{{4*cList.Page.Number}}</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="search(5)">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

(assuming the page number is stored in cList.Page, and starts with index 1)